# Excel - Looking at two cells, return the cell that is NOT equal to a value

Tags: excel, logic

Simple question: how do I return the value of a cell that is not equal to a certain value?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
CellOne = "certain term"
CellTwo = "otherValue"

IF CellOne or CellTwo = "certain term" THEN
RETURN Cell that is not equal to / does not contain "certain term" (in this case, CellTwo)
```

Preferably I would like to achieve this without using VBA.

**Further Info:**

This is a small part of a much larger multi-level nested `IF` statement and all other scenarios are already considered and have been taken into account; for now, all I need to work out is how to achieve this.

Comment: and what should happen if both fail? or both contain the "certain term"?

Comment: I should have said - this is part of a very large nested-IF that I'm working on, so no need to worry about that as those possibilities have already been accounted for; I just need to focus on this part for now.  Will update question accordingly.

Comment: Question now updated.

Comment: You have to post the full 'Truth table' to correctly answer this and avoid undefined behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a solution:

`=IF(H2="certain term",IF(H3="certain term",,H3),H2)`

A short description:

```
If CellOne has the value you don't want
    check if CellTwo has a value you don't want
              do nothing
          else show value from CellTwo
else show value from CellOne
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something you are probably looking for:

```
=IF(OR(A2="certain term", B2="certain term"), IF(A2="certain term", B2, A2))
```